# build.gradle migration from 8 to 9

Tags: java, gradle

Consider:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.johnrengelman:shadow:7.1.2"
    }
}



apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

// gradle 5.0+ compatibility
configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
// gradle 9.0+ compatibility
// change 

// tag::repositories[]
repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
}



application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'd20.App'
}

// end::repositories[]

// tag::dependencies[]
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'

}
```

Here is the warning:

> Build file
> '/home/bussiere/Workspace/CustomSystem/oldschooljava/build.gradle':
> line 19 Allowed usage is changing for configuration ':implementation',
> resolvable was false and is now true. Ideally, usage should be fixed
> upon creation. This behavior has been deprecated. This behavior is
> scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Usage should be fixed upon
> creation. Consult the upgrading guide for further information:
> https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#configurations_allowed_usage

I've tried to suppress the line:

> configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)

and replace it with

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        details.useVersion "latest.release"
    }
}
```

but it's not working.